# Automatic smooth scrolling Evince

Tags: evince, scrolling

I was wondering if there is a way to enable automatic smooth scrolling with evince pdf reader in ubuntu 18.04.
I know about the ctrl+arrows, but i usually scroll the vim way with k and j keys.
I can't quite pinpoint where the shortcuts and/or settings would be put, maybe in a configuration file that I can't find...?
Perhaps it is possible to remap the shortcut ctrl+arrows to j and k keys?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528080/how-can-i-change-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince-and-other-gnome-programs

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did find a link to file accels (put, for me, in ~/.config/evince/accels) with more entries than the one I have in my computer, which may therefore help with other remappings:
https://github.com/wesleybowman/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/evince/accels
Which points to several possible remapping. However, there is no specific coding for the smoooth scrolling in there, so it doesn't seem to  be linked with any particular action. I suppose it might be one level deeper, and I'm not so sure how to look for that.